# I can not use the method .equals(..), it throws NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
 req.getParameter("doit").equal("good");
```

Is it impossible to write this line in the
method? Without it, the program runs correctly. However whenever I write that line, it shows the error messages..

> java.lang.NullPointerException at adhoc.FinePrint.doFilter(FinePrint.java:50)

Is there any way that I can check whether "`doit`" parameter is equal to "`good`"??

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: It says "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. "

Comment: and "java.lang.NullPointerException
 at adhoc.FinePrint.doFilter(FinePrint.java:50)"

Comment: No you are seeing this error from the client side you have to check the error log on your server.

Comment: so that is the real problem `req.getParameter("doit")` is returning null.

Comment: But I checked that req.getParameter("doit") returns correct value.

Comment: Do you know the function is kind of recursive? make sure it has value on all the chain objects.

Comment: @BBbbBB Check my answer. Instead of use equal use equals method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to turn your equals around to

```
"good".equals(req.getParameter("doit"));
```

This prevents the NullPointerException when the request parameter "doit" is not set.